# Converting static website to wordpress issues with menus

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello I have a static website for a company made with bootstrap, html and css. I want to make the same website in wordpress. I have started learning wordpress today.

I have followed different tutorials to made my template for wordpress, I have managed to create the first index.php and it is working nicely. I have created about page too and it is also working good. But what i want now, I have menu in my header php, How to i add link to my wordpress pages?

This is my **header-top.php** im calling this in header.php, The menu is showing properly

```
<!-- HEADER TOP MENU-->navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-expanded">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll"  href="index.html">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/jms_logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right TopNav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="license.html">License</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="trainings.html">Trainings</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then i went to `wp-admin` and create a `about` page and added textual content to it and it is showing properly on this link `http://localhost/wordpress/about/`

Now my question is

**Q1**. How do i add this link of about page in my `header-top` menu page.

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="license.html">License</a></li>
```

Im totally new to wp so i'm not sure whatever i have done is the correct way of doing it or not? can u also suggest me some proper tutorials that i can understand easily to create my website.

**UPDATED MENU**

I have replaced this

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right TopNav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="license.html">License</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="trainings.html">Trainings</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with this but now the css for my menu is gone.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-top' ) ); ?>

    </div>
```

In my static website

[image]

In my WP

[image]

Updated 2 After inspecting elements, It is showing like this

[image]

but i want like this

[image]

Comment: Don't change or edit the WordPress default. Just edit the CSS. For eg if you already have css for only ul and li, now add it for div also. If your CSS looks like this **ul.nav .navbar-nav** then change it to **div.nav .navbar-nav ul**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For menus you should use standart `wp_nav_menu` function. It generates menu itself. So you should use something like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) { wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right TopNav', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) );}  ?>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right TopNav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="license.html">License</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="trainings.html">Trainings</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And when you add `wp_nav_menu` to your theme then option `MENU` should appear in `Appeareance` section on WP admin, where you can create new menu and assign it to `primary-menu` position in theme

**UPDATE**

You can generate only `li` items by using this method:

```
$options = array(
  'echo' => false
  ,'container' => false
);

$menu = wp_nav_menu($options);
echo preg_replace( array( '#^<ul [^>]*>#', '#</ul>$#' ), '', $menu );
```

So you can try something like this:

```
$options = array(
      'echo' => false
      ,'container' => false
    );

    $menu = wp_nav_menu($options);
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right TopNav">
          echo preg_replace( array( '#^<ul [^>]*>#', '#</ul>$#' ), '', $menu );
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is not properly showing menu which im showing using bootstrap, i have register menus in function and now it is showing in menu but the css is gone now, i have updated my code at the bottom of my question

Comment: @AsfiTanoli Try changing `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-top' ) ); ?>` to this one `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right TopNav', 'theme_location' => 'header-top' ) ); ?>` it should append classes to `ul`

Comment: It is still not showing properly, im adding screenshot in question

Comment: Then try include container in generation like this: INSTEAD OF `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-top' ) ); ?>

    </div>` USE: `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse', 'container_id' => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-2', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right TopNav', 'theme_location' => 'header-top' ) ); ?>`

Comment: It is still showing the same i already replaced with ur code.. also added screenshot of inspect element of old and new one.

Comment: @AsfiTanoli I have updated my answer with method, that looks most suitable for you, try that one under **UPDATE**